# Introducing TransactionScope into existing Project

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, snapshot-isolation

I would like to run one particular Linq2Sql query in snapshot isolation mode without affecting the rest of my application.

However whenever I use code like

```
using (var t = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, 
       new TransactionOptions { IsolationLevel =  IsolationLevel.Snapshot }))
{
    ...              
}
```

the Database is still using snapshot isolation after the transactionScope is finished.

I could add a dummy to reset the isolation mode like the following

```
using (var t = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, 
       new TransactionOptions { IsolationLevel =  IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted }))
{
    ...              
}
```

But this does not solve the problem that any queries started by other threads in between times would also be running in snapshot isolation.

It looks like, if I want to introduce a TransactionScope **anywhere** in my program, I have to use it **everywhere**.

Is that the case, or am I missing something?

Comment: That's quite hard to believe to be honest. How do you know that snaphost isolation is still used outside the scope?

Comment: @Evk The Sql command from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19102726/get-current-net-transactionscope-isolationlevel) returns snapshot. Also I tested using a `select * from table with (readpast)` which fails because I am now longer in ReadCommitted IsolationLevel

Comment: Was hard to believe but you are right. You can find more info about this in question I marked as duplicate.